# No se me actualiza variable "error_red"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Esta es una variable que debería actualizarse a cada vuelta, al igual que la variable "iteración"(esta sin funciona), pero no se actualiza. Cuando lo hago sin el modulo Parallel, funciona como debe. El problema viene cuando saco ese for de la funcion "iterar" y lo pongo en Parallel. No se si estoy imprimiendo mal o realmente siempre tiene el mismo valor

```html
        def iterar(iteracion):
            for i in range(len(self.entradas)):
                salidas_ocultas=[]
                for neurona in neuronas:
                    salida_oculta=neurona.obtener_salida(self.entradas[i])
                    salidas_ocultas.append(salida_oculta)
                # agregamos bias final
                salidas_ocultas.append(1)
                # recalculamos pesos finales
                salida_red=nf.obtener_salida(salidas_ocultas)
                salidas_red.append(salida_red)
                error_red=nf.obtener_error(self.salidas[i],salida_red)
                errores.append(error_red)
                delta_final=nf.obtener_delta_final(salida_red,error_red)
                variaciones=[]
                for salida in salidas_ocultas:
                    variacion=nf.variacion_pesos(salida,delta_final)
                    variaciones.append(variacion)
                
                nf.calcular_nuevos_pesos(variaciones)
                # recalculamos pesos ocultos
                variaciones=[]
                for neurona in neuronas:
                    salida=neurona.obtener_salida(self.entradas[i])
                    delta_oculto=neurona.obtener_delta_oculto(salida,delta_final)
                    for entrada in self.entradas[i]:
                        variacion=neurona.variacion_pesos(entrada,delta_oculto)
                        variaciones.append(variacion)
                    neurona.calcular_nuevos_pesos(variaciones)
            print("Iteracion ",iteracion+1)
            print(error_red)
       Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(iterar)(iteracion)for iteracion in range(iteraciones))

***
```

***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay un error en el código. En la función iterar(), estás tratando de acceder a la variable error_red fuera del ciclo for donde se define. Es decir, estás imprimiendo la variable error_red después del ciclo for, por lo que siempre imprimirá el valor de la última iteración del ciclo. Para solucionar este problema, debes mover la impresión de error_red dentro del ciclo for, de esta manera:

```
def iterar(iteracion):
    for i in range(len(self.entradas)):
        salidas_ocultas=[]
        for neurona in neuronas:
            salida_oculta=neurona.obtener_salida(self.entradas[i])
            salidas_ocultas.append(salida_oculta)
        # agregamos bias final
        salidas_ocultas.append(1)
        # recalculamos pesos finales
        salida_red=nf.obtener_salida(salidas_ocultas)
        salidas_red.append(salida_red)
        error_red=nf.obtener_error(self.salidas[i],salida_red)
        errores.append(error_red)
        delta_final=nf.obtener_delta_final(salida_red,error_red)
        variaciones=[]
        for salida in salidas_ocultas:
            variacion=nf.variacion_pesos(salida,delta_final)
            variaciones.append(variacion)

        nf.calcular_nuevos_pesos(variaciones)
        # recalculamos pesos ocultos
        variaciones=[]
        for neurona in neuronas:
            salida=neurona.obtener_salida(self.entradas[i])
            delta_oculto=neurona.obtener_delta_oculto(salida,delta_final)
            for entrada in self.entradas[i]:
                variacion=neurona.variacion_pesos(entrada,delta_oculto)
                variaciones.append(variacion)
            neurona.calcular_nuevos_pesos(variaciones)
        print("Iteracion ",iteracion+1)
        print(error_red)
Parallel(n_jobs=-1)(delayed(iterar)(iteracion)for iteracion in range(iteraciones))
```

Además, en la línea salidas_red.append(salida_red), parece que intentas agregar salida_red a una lista llamada salidas_red, pero esta lista no está definida en la función `iterar()

Comment: en realidad la idea es que toda esa función quede dentro del for que pongo en Parallel y que el error de red se muestra una cantidad de veces igual a iteraciones, entiendo lo que decís, pasa que me muestra mas veces de lo que necesito el error y sigue sin cambiar